# Discord.py how to create choice with slash command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13efi.png)

I need to do like this in discord.py slash command and i dont know how to do

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use it like this.

Imports:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from typing import List
```

```
    @app_commands.command(name="rps")
    @app_commands.choices(choices=[
        app_commands.Choice(name="Rock", value="rock"),
        app_commands.Choice(name="Paper", value="paper"),
        app_commands.Choice(name="Scissors", value="scissors"),
        ])
    async def rps(self, i: discord.Interaction, choices: app_commands.Choice[str]):
        if (choices.value == 'rock'):
            counter = 'paper'
        elif (choices.value == 'paper'):
            counter = 'scissors'
        else:
            counter = 'rock'
        # rest of your command
```

Here's another way to do it with autocomplete:

```
    async def rps_autocomplete(self,
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        current: str,
    ) -> List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
        choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
        return [
            app_commands.Choice(name=choice, value=choice)
            for choice in choices if current.lower() in choice.lower()
        ]

    # play rock paper scissors
    @app_commands.command(name="rps")
    @app_commands.autocomplete(choices=rps_autocomplete)
    async def rps(self, i: discord.Interaction, choices:str):
        choices = choices.lower()
        if (choices == 'rock'):
            counter = 'paper'
        elif (choices == 'paper'):
            counter = 'scissors'
        else:
            counter = 'rock'
        # rest of your command
```

Also, check [this](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/c4324f17a80c94776832430007ad40e6#choices) out for more.

If your command is not gonna be in a cog:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="rps")
@app_commands.choices(choices=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="Rock", value="rock"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="Paper", value="paper"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="Scissors", value="scissors"),
    ])
async def rps(i: discord.Interaction, choices: app_commands.Choice[str]):
    if (choices.value == 'rock'):
        counter = 'paper'
    elif (choices.value == 'paper'):
        counter = 'scissors'
    else:
        counter = 'rock'
    # rest of your command
```

Assuming your bot is defined like this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="r.", intents=intents)
```

Comment: sorrry what to import

Comment: @SurawitJongjarearn I added the imports.

Comment: @SurawitJongjarearn I also added another snippet. You can use it, if your command is not going to be in a cog.

Comment: In python 3.9+ [list can be used instead of typing.List](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/).